# Is making web service calls in Apple watch best practice?

Tags: swift, web-services, xcode7, watchos-2

I am making an app for watch OS2  .I have to make some service calls to get some JSON Data for my watch app. What is the place to make service call?Shall I do it in the phone and then transfer data via watchkit connectivity or I can directly call from watchkit app. ?

**P.S :** My app will consume a simple json data to populate from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not that simple, there is a whole wwdc session about it.

Learn about App Transport Security, HTTP/2 protocol support, new NSURLSession API, and best practices for networking in apps, extensions, and WatchKit apps:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/711/